# Buscar dados do produto ao escanear código de barras

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Boa noite pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em JSP e nele tenho um formulário para o usuário cadastrar um produto.

Minha dúvida é, se existe algum meio de, quando o cliente escanear o código de barras do produto no input "Código", o javascript fizesse uma busca em algum lugar fora do sistema (no caso acho que usando AJAX) e retornasse os dados do produto referente aquele código, exibindo nos campos devidos.

Porque da dúvida? Eu sei que todos os produtos que possuem um código de barras são registrados em alguma entidade que faz o gerenciamento desses códigos, por isso acredito que deva ter alguma maneira de fazer o que pretendo, só não consegui encontrar.

Se alguém souber, irá me ajduar demais, pois é para o meu TCC!

Answer (score 0):

Sim e não. Cada empresa pode gerar o código que bem entender para os seus códigos de barras. Contudo, por interesses comerciais as grandes marcas definem seus padrões e existem algumas iniciativas que centralizam essa informação que podem auxiliar na identificação de um item por seu código de barras. Você pode dar uma olhada em [OPD- Open Product Database](https://product-open-data.com/)

Por padrão todo item ao ser cadastrado em um inventário tem seu código registrado, para que o mesmo seja reconhecido posteriormente no momento da leitura.